# Android - Separate links for custom ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview

I've been working on this for roughly an hour now and have not had any success. What I am trying to do is apply different actions for my two ListView objects, but the both respond to only one, which is the external link. How do I make them each have their own action? I can provide more code upon request

Here is my code:

```java
package net.androidbootcamp.gamesandcoffee;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;



public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    ListView listView;
    int[] list_image_resource = {R.drawable.games, R.drawable.coffee};
    String[] list_titles;
    String[] list_descriptions;
    ListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        list_descriptions = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.description);
        list_titles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        int i=0;
        adapter = new ListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        for(String titles: list_titles)
        {
            GameDataProvider dataProvider = new GameDataProvider(list_image_resource[i],
                    titles, list_descriptions[i]);
            adapter.add(dataProvider);
            i++;
        }
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, games.class));
            }
        });
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee")));
            }
        });
    }


}
```

And here is my XML for Main:

```xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#BBBBBB"
    >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And XML for my ListView adapter:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#BBBBBB">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/layout_image"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/coffee"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/layout_image"
        android:text="This is the title"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/list_description"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/layout_image"
        android:paddingTop="35dp"
        android:paddingLeft="40dp"
        android:text="This is the description"
        />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item_title">

    </View>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you have two onItemClickListners_

Comment: @Dhina I am not sure myself. It's obviously wrong, likely a beginner mistake on my part, trying to make it more complicated than it needed to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, games.class));
        }
    });
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee")));
        }
    });
```

with

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

           if(position == 0){

            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, games.class));

           }else
           {
              startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee")));
           }

        }
    });
```

You are setting two listeners, So the last listener you have set is always considered. So, you always end up navigating to external link.

Cheers,
sree

Answer (score 0):

Use only one

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //Do If else statement here to cross check which item you clicked by using position 
            }
        });
```